# Google Drive api How to create folders with keeping folder's structure

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-drive-api

I am trying to create folders into google drive. Actually what I am doing is taking a folder from my computer as an input and insert its structure to google drive. Also I am trying to insert the files which the folder has to google drive also but this function is not important for now. First I should create new folder tree inside google drive. I am using drive api and after taking input folder I parse their path and put them in an array. Then I manage the creation of new folders according to these arrays. But Where I stuck is creating nested folders. For example I create a 'documents' folder and then try to create a 'files' folder inside the 'documents' folder. However before creating 'files' folder I need the id of 'documents' folder so I can assign it as parent to 'files' folder. And I should do the creation of folders inside a for loop one after another. The problem is that when I make a request for 'documents' folder I have to wait request.execute() funtion to get its id. Before I get the id request for 'files' is sent but it cannot take id as parameter so I cannot create nested folders. Here is an example input folder structure to make problem clear. [image] I want to create this folder structure inside google drive. Also here is my code.

```
<html>
   <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
    var webviewlink = "";
    var parentID = [{ id: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" }];
    var fileName = "newFolder";
    var fileNamesArr = [];
    var fileIdArr = [];

    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    /**
     * Called when the client library is loaded to start the auth flow.
     */
    function handleClientLoad() {
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Check if the current user has authorized the application.
     */
    function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
            { 'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true },
            handleAuthResult);
    }

    /**
     * Called when authorization server replies.
     *
     * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
     */
    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authButton = document.getElementById('authorizeButton');
        var filePicker = document.getElementById('filePicker');
        authButton.style.display = 'none';
        filePicker.style.display = 'none';
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to the API.
            filePicker.style.display = 'block';              
            filePicker.onchange = uploadFile;
        } else {
            // No access token could be retrieved, show the button to start the authorization flow.
            authButton.style.display = 'block';
            authButton.onclick = function () {
                gapi.auth.authorize(
                    { 'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': false },
                    handleAuthResult);
            };
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start the file upload.
     *
     * @param {Object} evt Arguments from the file selector.
     */
    function uploadFile(evt) {

        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        var totalFiles = files.length; // length of array

        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function () {
            for (var k = 0; k < totalFiles; k++) {
                var file = evt.target.files[k];
                var tmp = file.webkitRelativePath;
                var pathNamesArr = tmp.split('/');

                console.debug(file);
                output.innerText = output.innerText + file.webkitRelativePath + "\n";

                for (var i = 0; i < pathNamesArr.length; i++) {
                    if (!isFile(pathNamesArr[i]) && searchNames(fileNamesArr, pathNamesArr[i])) {
                        for (var t = 0; t < fileNamesArr.length; t++) {
                            if (fileNamesArr[t] === pathNamesArr[i]) {
                                parentID[0].id = fileIdArr[t].id;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!isFile(pathNamesArr[i]) && !searchNames(fileNamesArr, pathNamesArr[i])) {
                        fileNamesArr.push(pathNamesArr[i]);
                         createNewFile(pathNamesArr[i], parentID, false);  //inserts new folders here
                    }

                    else if (isFile(pathNamesArr[i])) {
                        insertFile(file);
                    }
                }                   
            }
        });
    }

    /** 
     * Insert new file.
     *
     * @param {File} fileData File object to read data from.
     * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
     */
    function insertFile(fileData, callback) {
        const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
        const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
            var metadata = {
                'title': fileData.name,
                'mimeType': contentType,
                'parents': parentID
            };

            output.innerText = output.innerText + " insert id = " + parentID[0].id + "\n";

            var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
            var multipartRequestBody =
                delimiter +
                'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
                JSON.stringify(metadata) +
                delimiter +
                'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
                '\r\n' +
                base64Data +
                close_delim;

            var request = gapi.client.request({
                'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
                'method': 'POST',
                'params': { 'uploadType': 'multipart' },
                'headers': {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
                },
                'body': multipartRequestBody,
            });

            /*   var request = gapi.client.request({
                   'path': '/drive/v2/files',
                   'method': 'POST',
                   'params': { 'uploadType': 'multipart' },
                   'body': {
                       "title": "cat",
                       "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
                       "description": "Some"
                   }
               });*/

            if (!callback) {
                callback = function (file) {
                    console.log(file)
                };
            }
            request.execute(callback);
        }
    }

    //Extra Part
    function createNewFile(fileName, parentFileId, isPublic) {
        output.innerText = output.innerText + " girdi createnewfile2" + fileName + " " + parentFileId[0].id +  "\n";

        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function () {

            output.innerText = output.innerText + " girdi gapi" + "\n";

            var request = gapi.client.request({
                'path': '/drive/v2/files',
                'method': 'POST',
                'body': {
                    "title": fileName,
                    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
                    "description": "Some",
                    "parents": parentFileId
                }
            });

            if (isPublic) {
                request.execute(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    parentID = resp.id;
                    fileIdArr.push({ id : resp.id });
                    var permissionBody = {
                        'value': '',
                        'type': 'anyone',
                        'role': 'reader'
                    };
                    var permissionRequest = gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
                        'fileId': resp.id,
                        'resource': permissionBody
                    });
                    permissionRequest.execute(function (resp) { });
                });
            }
            else {
                request.execute(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    output.innerText = output.innerText + " my new id = " + resp.id + "\n";
                    parentID = resp.id;
                    fileIdArr.push({ id : resp.id });
                });
            }
        });
    }
    //Search the names
    function searchNames(namesArr, name) {
        if (namesArr.length === 0)
            return false;
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < namesArr.length; i++) {
                if (namesArr[i] === name)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Path is file or directory
    function isFile(myName) {
        for(var i = 0; i < myName.length; i++){
            if (myName.indexOf(".txt") > -1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<div>       
    <input type="file" id="filePicker" multiple directory webkitdirectory mozdirectory />
    <input type="button" id="authorizeButton" style="display: none" value="Authorize" />        
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: You've kinda answered your own question with "I have to wait request.execute() funtion to get its id." That's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I understand the issue and I tried  setTimeout(function(){ },3500) inside the for however it did not work. Do you have any idea How can I delay the function before executing next iteration of the loop?

Comment: no. read about basics of asynchronous functions in javascript. tldr: chain them.

Comment: setTimeout is almost always the wrong answer to the problem of calling aynchronous tasks. In the case of JavaScript/Drive, you need to create a function that deals with receiving the Drive response, and then using that to instigate the successor task. Are you using any framework such as AngularJS, or plain old JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you both Zig and pinoyyid.I want to use angular js because I am trying to learn angular recently but for now I am just trying to modify the drive api example codes to get a function which gives me what I want. I can say I am familiar with angular do you have any suggestions?